# my omnigrid looks different from the official demo in google chrome

Tags: html, css, mootools, omnigrid

this is how official demo looks:
[image]

this is mine:
[image]

the button at top of the grid is not verticaly centered,the paging bar at bottom of my gird also looks ugly.

my code html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="omnigrid.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
 body{font-size:11px}
.omnigrid div.fbutton .add {
 background:transparent url(images/add.png) no-repeat scroll left center;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.2-more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="omnigrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border:1px solid #cde;padding:25px 25px 25px 25px">
 <div id="mygrid"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

my code javascript :

```
function onGridSelect(evt) {
 var str = 'row: ' + evt.row + ' indices: ' + evt.indices;
 str += ' id: ' + evt.target.getDataByRow(evt.row).id;
 alert(str);
}

function gridButtonClick(button, grid) {
 alert(button);
}

var cmu = [ {
 header : "ID",
 dataIndex : 'help_category_id',
 dataType : 'number'
}, {
 header : "Parent ID",
 dataIndex : 'parent_category_id',
 dataType : 'number',
 width : 50
}, {
 header : "Name",
 dataIndex : 'name',
 dataType : 'string',
 width : 200
} ];

window.addEvent("load", function() {

 datagrid = new omniGrid('mygrid', {
  columnModel : cmu,
  buttons : [ {
   name : 'Add',
   bclass : 'add',
   onclick : gridButtonClick
  }, {
   name : 'Delete',
   bclass : 'delete',
   onclick : gridButtonClick
  }, {
   separator : true
  }, {
   name : 'Duplicate',
   bclass : 'duplicate',
   onclick : gridButtonClick
  } ],
  url : "data.jsp?" + Math.random(),
  perPageOptions : [ 10, 20, 50, 100, 200 ],
  perPage : 10,
  page : 1,
  pagination : true,
  serverSort : true,
  showHeader : true,
  alternaterows : true,
  sortHeader : false,
  resizeColumns : true,
  multipleSelection : true,

  // uncomment this if you want accordion behavior for every row
  /*
  accordion:true,
  accordionRenderer:accordionFunction,
  autoSectionToggle:false,
   */

  width : 600,
  height : 220
 });

 datagrid.addEvent('click', onGridSelect);
 $$(".omnigrid .pDiv").each(e,function (){
  e.setStyle('font-size','11px');
 });
});
```

Comment: this looks like a CSS error rather than a mootools one.

Answer (score 0):

It look like a css line-height problem. Use Chrome's Web Inspector (View > Developer > Web inspector), click on the magnifying glass and select the table header. Check the line-height property. Is it any different from the omnigrid demo?

For a quick dirty fix add:

```
.omnigrid {
  line-height: 120% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys, the problem is caused by myself, I zoomed out the page in google chrome